# Google chrome and html update

Tags: html

I'm building a web site whose hosting supports html and javascript. When I update the html pages, I noticed that some Chrome versions couldn't show the pages updated. It shows old html. I wonder how I can fix this. I guess `<META HTTP-EQUIV="expires"CONTENT="0">` won't work.

Comment: You should have spaces between your attributes, and not use ALL CAPS. `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">`. Looks much better (and might actually work!).

Comment: i m seeing that all ie9 and chrome, probably other browsers can't update the page. besides i added the code above. i must say that the address at the address bar remains static while navigating between pages.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably just the browser caching the HTML.

CTRL + F5 will do a force refresh and will probably solve your issue.

Comment: which versions of Chrome are you experiencing problems with and are they versions any of your visitors might be using?

Comment: i downloaded latest version 15 it has no problem. but one of my friend has version 16 (with an alert at about box) it can't show updated pages. some other people complain too.

Answer (score 0):

Select Tools -> Clear Browsing data from Chrome menu.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i can clear chrome cookies but visitors might not.